# How to check if an Ember Data model instance already exists in the local store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With Ember Data, how can I test whether a model instance already exists in the local store?

Assume an Ember Data model type named `App.User = DS.Model.extend({ ... })`.

`someUser = App.User.find(someId)` may or may not issue an XHR to the remote server depending on whether a record with `someId` already exists in the local store. Before issuing that XHR, I'd like to first check for existence of such a record in the local store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DS.Store.hasRecordForId(type, id)`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_hasRecordForId).

Answer (score 3):

While not as efficient as digging into the store's cache for a particular `id`, `DS.Model` comes with an `all()` method that is clean and useful in this situation. `App.User.all()` returns a filtered array containing all known `User` records, so one way to check for the existence of a record with a given `id` is the following:

```
var isLoaded = App.User.all().some(function(user) {
  return user.get('id') === someId;
});
```

Comment: Can this be used in the model's `find` method? I'm trying to simulate ajax requests by adding a delay, but I'd like to return the model from the store if it has already been requested.

Comment: I don't see why not, but keep in mind that this is a very inefficient way to check for the existence of a record. You wouldn't want to do this for every `find`. Somewhere internal to Ember-Data is a hash that would be much faster to check.